# What happens if you drive in British Columbia on a foreign license for more than 3 months?

Tags: canada, driving-license

I'm planning a move to Canada and apparently you have to give up your old license in order to get a local one. This would be extremely inconvenient as I would then have issues with driving back in Czech Republic whenever I visit, since I won't give up my residency.

What is the current penalty for driving in B.C. (Canada) for more than 3 months without exchanging your license? And is it common for police officers to enforce it?

Comment: Surely the Czech Republic would recognize a Canadian license with an IDP for short-term visits.

Comment: @choster well... technically, since Czech Republic would still have me as a resident (which is different from being a *tax resident*), I must drive on a Czech license. I'm sure I could convince the local policemen of my status somehow, but it would be easier to avoid a change in the first place. Canada also requires a driving test from Czech license holders, which is another hassle.

Comment: If Canada requires a driving test, you might as well just treat it as a new license and not bother to tell them you already hold a Czech license.

Comment: @GregHewgill Ha, that was first thought too. But they have a "learner permit" system where you won't get a fully valid license for the first 2 years.

Comment: Get the paperwork you need (driving experience, etc.) from the Czech authorities. "Lose" your Czech license and get a replacement. Hand over the "lost" one to BC.

Comment: Is it legal to maintain residence in the Czech republic when you're actually spending most of your time in Canada?

Comment: @mkennedy that would be fraud, which is a criminal offense.

Comment: @phoog yes, Czech laws in this regard are extremely simple. Note that this is different from being a tax resident.

Comment: Well then if you are correct that it's not also fraudulent to maintain your resident status in the Czech republic when you do not actually reside there, then it seems you must choose between that and being able to drive legally in British Columbia after having been there for more than 3 months; the BC law seems unambiguous that you can't have two licenses.  (If BC is like the US states I'm familiar with, the legal penalty after 90 days is the same as for being unlicensed, and on top of that any local insurance you may purchase will be invalid.)

Comment: @phoog feel free to add that as an answer. I'm now thinking the Czechs shouldn't be so strict since even driving without a license (if you have one but forgot it at home) is only a 2 euro fine.

Comment: @phoog as for the residency - the Czech law is designed as a countermeasure to government control. It's legal to live in the country (as a citizen) without being a resident and even legal to be a resident without a residential address (in this case the town hall will be your contact point).

Comment: @phoog, BC law is more-or-less the same as Ontario law. It isn't that you can't have two licenses, it is only that they really want to take your old license when they  swap for one of their's. When I moved to Canada I gave up a California license for an Ontario one. When I moved back to California I applied for a new California license, since I still had a car in Ontario that required that license to keep insured and California won't swap for a foreign license anyway, so I now have two licenses. It would be illegal to not present the ON license when there, otherwise all is well.

Comment: @Dennis I am just going by the official source in OP's [related question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/is-the-3-month-limit-on-driving-with-your-foreign-license-valid-for-each-individ) (http://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/moving-bc/Pages/Moving-from-another-country.aspx).  It says "B.C. law requires that you only have one driver's licence."  I did not look up the actual law to see what it actually says.

Comment: @phoog, [It is at 25(5) in this law](http://www.bclaws.ca/EPLibraries/bclaws_new/document/ID/freeside/96318_01#section25), but I think it is fairly well understood that this is best interpreted as "If you have a BC license any other card you have is not a license (in BC)" since what cards you keep in your drawer at home, and what you (are required to) legitimately use when driving outside of Canada aren't really topics they can legislate about.

Comment: @Dennis That's actually a good interpretation. Especially if the second driving license is stored in a different country.

Comment: This really makes little sense. Why would they want to take away your old license if you prove you can get one for use in Canada. It's not like it's nationality/passport or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [BC government](http://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/transportation/driving-and-cycling/road-safety-rules-and-consequences/driving-without-valid-drivers-licence):

> The consequences of driving without a valid driver’s licence are
>   severe in this province. As a deterrent to individuals who continue to
>   drive illegally, the consequences ramp up.
>
> 1st time – The first time police find you driving unlicensed, you will
>   receive a violation ticket for driving without a valid driver’s
>   licence. You will not be permitted to drive the vehicle any further on
>   the road.
>
> 2nd time – When found a second time driving without a valid driver's
>   licence, the notice on your driving record will inform the police that
>   you have a previous 'No Driver’s Licence' conviction and state they
>   will immediately impound the vehicle you are driving for seven days,
>   whether it is owned by you or not. You will immediately be prohibited
>   from driving. The driving prohibition period is indefinite – it will
>   continue until you get a valid B.C. driver’s licence, meeting all
>   other licensing requirements you may have had placed on you, such as
>   paying any and all outstanding traffic fines.
>
> Subsequently: If you continue to operate a motor vehicle after being
>   prohibited from driving, you will be charged with ‘Driving While
>   Prohibited’ which is punishable by a $500 fine and up to six months in
>   jail for a first offence.

There are more pdfs of the fines etc at the bottom of the page.

It's also worth noting a potentially more critical implication - if your license has 'expired' (as in you've been more than 90 days without changing it), you essentially have no license (as above).  What this means though, is in the event of an accident, you WILL NOT BE INSURED.  And that could be a far more costly experience than any small fine from the government, in the event of an incident.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with the conclusion that waiting more than 90 days after moving is the same as a license expiry.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk It's not the same, but the effect is the same.  If your license is expired or is no longer valid due to your settlement in B.C., you are driving without a valid license.  That means you're subject to a ticket for doing so, and your insurance is no longer valid.