# Is the 3 month limit on driving with your foreign license valid for each individual province or for Canada as a whole?

Tags: canada, driving-license

According to the [ICBC website](http://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/moving-bc/Pages/Moving-from-another-country.aspx):

> Welcome to B.C.! After moving here, you have 90 days to switch over your valid licence to a B.C. driver’s licence.

Does this limit apply to all of Canada or does it only apply for B.C.? E.g. if I were to fly to Alberta after staying in Canada for more than 3 months, could I still use my home license?

Comment: Interesting thought! Note however that not all provincees have the 90 day limit - Ontario for example [is 60 days](https://www.angloinfo.com/how-to/canada/transport/driving-licences/exchanging-a-licence).

Comment: In the US it's per state; I expect it's the same in Canada.  Note that it's "after moving," so if you visit any Canadian province for six months with the intention of returning to your foreign residence, that is, you haven't *moved* there, you should be able to drive on your foreign license the whole time.  So if you move to BC for 90 days or less and then move to another province, you should get a new grace period in the new province.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 month restriction comes from the Motor Vehicles Act passed by the BC government and therefore it is only applicable to public roads in British Columbia. When traveling to another Canadian province your counter resets and you can drive there freely without a Canadian license.

Answer (score 1):

That time limit only applies if you move to British Columbia (and it varies by province).  If you are only visiting as a tourist, there is no requirement to change to a Canadian provincial or territorial license.  If in doubt, check with the motor vehicle service in the province or territory in question.  Taking up employment generally will make you a resident and the timer will start; visiting as a tourist only, or attending school full-time, generally does not.